# filter a list with useReducer hook in React?

Tags: reactjs, filter, state, dispatch, use-reducer

I need to know how I can filter an object with the useReducer function in the form of a list. I want it to work based on the object's progress. I'm new, do I need to map something too?

```
const data = {
  title: "Title",
  lessons: [
    {
      title: "Introduction",
      data: Lesson1,
      isComplete: false,
      progress: 0,
    },
    {
      title: "Section",
      data: Lesson2,
      isComplete: false,
      progress: 10,
    },
    {
      title: "Review",
      data: Lesson3,
      isComplete: false,
      progress: 0,
    },
  ],
};
```

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, data.lessons);

  function reducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "all":
        return { ...state.filter((filterlesson) => filterlesson >= 0) };
      case "viewed":
        return { ...state.filter((filterlesson) => filterlesson != 0) };
      case "notviewed":
        return { ...state.filter((filterlesson) => filterlesson == 0) };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

```
const Filter = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <div className={styles.filter}>
          <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "all" })}>All</button>
          <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "viewed" })}>Viewed</button>
          <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "notviewed" })}>Not Viewed</button>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  };
```

```
return (
    <Fragment>
        <Filter />
        {state}
    </Fragment>
  );
```

I was trying this before but think should be using useReducer :

```
        {data.lessons
            .filter((l) => l.progress === 0)
            .map((filterLesson, i) => (
              <li key={i}></li>
            ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the RIGHT way but its a way I came up with without useReducer. Any optimization would be welcomed!

```
const [filterState, setfilterState] = useState(data.lessons);

  const allLessons = useMemo(() => {
    return data.lessons.filter((less) => less.progress >= 0);
  });
  const viewedLessons = useMemo(() => {
    return data.lessons.filter((less) => less.progress != 0);
  });
  const notViewedLessons = useMemo(() => {
    return data.lessons.filter((less) => less.progress == 0);
  });
```

```
 const Filter = () => {
    return ( 
       <div >
          <button
            onclick={() => {
              setfilterState(allLessons);
            }}
          >
            All Lessons
          </button>
          <button
            onclick={() => {
              setfilterState(viewedLessons);
            }}
          >
            Viewed
          </button>
          <button size="1em" onclick={() => {
              setfilterState(notViewedLessons);
            }}
          >
            Not Viewed
          </button>
        </div>
)
};

 const List = () => {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className={styles.list}>
          {filterState.map((item, i) => (
            <li key={i}>{item}</li>
          ))}
      </Fragment>
    );
  };
```

```
return (
    <Fragment>
        <Filter />
        <List />
    </Fragment>
  );
```